# Perform a docker-compose pull via Ansible

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ansible

#### Question

With the Ansible `docker_compose` module is it possible to perform a `docker-compose pull` and/or `docker-compose build` without actually starting the service?

---

#### What have I tried?

I've attempted:

```
    - name: Build & pull services
      become: yes
      docker_compose:
        project_src: "{{ installation_path }}"
        build: yes
        state: present
        stopped: yes
```

but this seems to start the services as well (even though I have `stopped: yes`).

---

#### Use case

The actual situation is that starting the services causes ports conflicts with existing processes. So the idea is to:

- Stop the conflicting processes
- Start the docker services

The problem is that one of these processes is the one that resolves DNS queries so stopping the processes and starting the docker services leads to an attempt to fetch the docker images from the docker registry, failing with a DNS resolution error.

My idea was to:

- Pull every necessary image
- Stop the conflicting processes
- Start the docker services

Comment: The docs appear to have a pull option. In this case have you tried removing the `state` and setting `pull: yes`? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_compose_module.html#parameter-pull

Comment: @AndyShinn Yes. I've also tried with `pull: yes` and `recreate: never` (the docs seem to imply that sometimes it restarts and recreates containers after a build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this Github issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/31924) this is not possible and will likely remain so in the near future given that the `docker_*` [is not actively maintained](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/31924#issuecomment-457923628).

Answer (score 0):

It's working no. Take a look at [the issue here](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.docker/issues/12)

```
      community.docker.docker_compose:
        project_src: src
        pull: true
        state: present
```